# grouping divs with same attribute with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to group the divs with the same attribute and put them into a container div. The divs are generated. The structure looks like this.

```
<div class="cleanse">A</div>
        <div class="treat">B</div>
        <div class="prime">C</div>

        <br><br><br>
        <div class="product"><img alt="red" src="http://aar.co/508-859-thickbox/therapy-ball-small-red.jpg" width="100px"></div>
        <div class="product"><img alt="blue" src="http://www.valleyvet.com/swatches/11178_L_230_vvs.jpg" width="100px"></div>
        <div class="product"><img alt="red" src="http://aar.co/508-859-thickbox/therapy-ball-small-red.jpg" width="100px"></div>
        <div class="product"><img alt="yellow" src="http://debenhams.scene7.com/is/image/Debenhams/304028400423?$ProdLarge$" width="100px"></div>
        <div class="product"><img alt="blue" src="http://www.valleyvet.com/swatches/11178_L_230_vvs.jpg" width="100px"></div>
```

And the script what I have so far which is not working is

```
$(function(){
        $('.product').each(function(){
            if ($(this).is('[red]')) {
                $(this).appendTo($('.cleanse'));
            } else {
                 if ($(this).is('[blue]')) {
                        $(this).appendTo($('.treat'));
                 } else {
                      if ($(this).is('[yellow]')) {
                        $(this).appendTo($('.prime'));  
                      }
                 }
            }
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) filter:

```
$(function() {
    var $products = $('.product');

    $products.filter(':has([alt=red])').appendTo('.cleanse');
    $products.filter(':has([alt=blue])').appendTo('.treat');
    $products.filter(':has([alt=yellow])').appendTo('.prime');
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qxRY4/1/

---

If you're dealing with a larger dataset, you might want to use a loop instead. Here's how:

```
$(function() {
    var $products = $('.product');
    var map = {
        red: 'cleanse',
        blue: 'treat',
        yellow: 'prime'
    };

    $.each(map, function (attr, className) {
        $products.filter(':has([alt=' + attr + '])').appendTo('.' + className);
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qxRY4/2/

Comment: This could be (possibly) improved by making a map array `[{key:"red", value:".cleanse"}, {key:"blue",value:".treat"}, {key:"yellow",value:".prime"}]` and then looping over that with a method containing something like `$products.filter('has([alt=' + obj.key + '])').appendTo(obj.value);`

Comment: @Jeff - If you don't mind me asking: how is that an improvement? [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) is only good if the result is simpler; for such a small dataset, I think avoiding the loop removes a lot of unnecessary abstraction.

Comment: Absolutely. That's why I said "(possibly)" - if the OP (or a future reader) has 40 of these things it'd be clearer to use a function.

Comment: The array would be helpful if the dataset is huge. Which I can definitely see happening in next couple of months.

Comment: @soum - Sure thing. I added the looping method to my answer.

Comment: @Joseph -Thanks man. That was a pretty sweet solution. I used your updated version

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function(){
    var colorMap = {red: "cleanse", blue: "treat", yellow: "prime"};
    $('.product > img').each(function(){
        var el = $(this);
        el.appendTo($('.' + colorMap[el.attr('alt')]));
    });    
});
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('alt')` will get nothing because the `img` has `alt`, not the div.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/y9CS7/2/

```
$(function() {
    var $prod = $('.product');

    $prod.find('[alt="red"]').appendTo($('.cleanse'));
    $prod.find('[alt="blue"]').appendTo($('.treat'));
    $prod.find('[alt="yellow"]').appendTo($('.prime'));
});
```

This will move the parent `<div>`

```
$(function() {
    var $prod = $('.product');

    $prod.find('[alt="red"]').parent().appendTo($('.cleanse'));
    $prod.find('[alt="blue"]').parent().appendTo($('.treat'));
    $prod.find('[alt="yellow"]').parent().appendTo($('.prime'));
});
```

Comment: OP want to move the divs not the images

Comment: If you intend to move the whole `<div>` please use Joseph Silber's answer. Thanks Musa for pointing out +1.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the iteration on `.product`, first you need to select the img tag, not only this, since this would be the div, not the image tag with the alt:

```
$(function(){
        $('.product').each(function(){
            if ($("img",this).is('[alt="red"]')) {
                $(this).appendTo('.cleanse');
            } else {
                 if ($("img",this).is('[alt="blue"]')) {
                        $(this).appendTo('.treat');
                 } else {
                      if ($("img",this).is('[alt="yellow"]')) {
                        $(this).appendTo('.prime');  
                      }
                 }
            }
        }
});
```